# Typescript custom d.ts files

Tags: jquery, typescript, types

I have a project that I am converting to Typescript. I have downloaded the newest @types and am attempting to create a custom.d.ts file. The file looks like this so far:

```
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts"/>

interface jQuery{
    iCheck(): JQuery;
    bootstrapSwitch(): JQuery;
}

interface jQueryStatic{
    notific8(): JQuery;
}

declare var notific8: JQueryStatic;
declare var isCheck: JQuery;
declare var bootstrapSwitch: JQuery;
```

In my file that I am trying to use the definitions in I make a reference to it using

```
/// <reference path="../utility/custom.d.ts" />
```

Visual studio recognizes that the paths are correct but when I hover over the code that implements it I get:

```
[ts] Property 'notific8' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic<HTMLElement>'
```

and

```
[ts] Property 'iCheck' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
[ts] Property 'bootstrapSwitch' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
```

Ive tried moving the declare lines into the app file but I still get the same error? Does anybody know why Typescript isn't recognizing it? I am using typescript 2.5.2 and "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12" Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be, because you have variables of types `JQuery`, not `jQuery`.

Same applies for `JQueryStatic`(should be `jQueryStatic` for Typescript to recognize `notific8` property)